# php virtual function causes blank page

Tags: php, apache, lamp

the following code produces a blank page, and no error in the error logs:

```
<?php virtual('/inc/doctype.html'); ?>
```

I have checked that the file exists and is reachable.

Comment: I presume you are using Apache, and running PHP as an Apache module and not as CGI?  Have you enabled error logging/reporting?

Comment: Unless Im confused, yes it is a module, I have LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so in my conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I recall, this is what I ended up doing to fix it:**

I have done this plenty of times before, I must have just overlooked it this time.
I had to make two changes to my apache2 site configuration file and run "a2enmod include" and I think that was it.

**Config changes**

Includes added to Options directive and addoutputfilter for includes in php file, as seen below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    *** Irrelivent elements removed ***
  <Directory /usr/local/www/e/eisenhowerimaging/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
    *** Irrelivent elements removed ***
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php
  </Directory>
    *** Irrelivent elements removed ***
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double Check your path.

*sorry, read the question wrong earlier*

Comment: Yeah my bad, I read it as he was inserting a php file earlier.